# Match every word except for those specified

Tags: regex, perl

Given the following `string`:

`Some Name Season 1`

I am trying to match:

`Some Name` (ideally in 1 capturing group)

The part I am trying to match may not necessarily be two words AND could occur before or after `Season X` where `X` is a number.

`Examples:`

`Some Name A B Season 23` returns `Some Name A B`

`Season 23 Some Name A B C D` returns `Some Name A B C D`

Currently I have:

```
(?!Season\s*\d+)\b\w+
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @hwnd I added more details in the question.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @hwnd I'm using Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the language you are using, you could use the [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) feature.

```
(?|Season \d+ (.*)|(.*) Season \d+)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uV3aL0/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know about this operator either. This will actually come in handy in another part of my code where I was manually testing each match :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will work with your sample data:

```
(.+)Season\s?\d+|Season\s\d+(.+)
```

It accounts for `Season` coming before and after, and `Some Name` is captured into `$1`.

Hopefully it works for your needs :)